# How best to convert Tait-Bryan angles to Euler Angles? For VR Controller project.

Tags: rotations, quaternions, orientation

Again I have played with magicks beyond my understanding.

I have a unique problem: I'm trying to interface three programs that no one has ever tried, in an effort to make a cheap VR controller.

I am using PSMoveServiceEX (https://github.com/Timocop/PSMoveServiceEx) which gets position and orientation data from Playstation Move Controllers. I then use PSMoveFreePIEBridge (https://github.com/HipsterSloth/PSMoveFreepieBridge) to transfer position and orientation data to FreePIE (https://github.com/AndersMalmgren/FreePIE) I then map various buttons and axes, as well as manipulate the orientation data. That data gets fed to the Razer Hydra plugin, which I'm using SteamVR Driver for Razer Hydra to feed the data into SteamVR.

And to top it all off, the pitch of the controller when seen in SteamVR is off by +45 degrees.

I have observed the output from PSMoveServiceEX as described in its orientation tests as "altitude", "heading, and "bank". These are obviously Pitch, Yaw, and Roll. However, the output of the bank/roll and is unique, as you rotate the controller clockwise from 0-90 degrees, the value goes from 0 to -90. However, as you continue from 90-180 degrees roll, the value decreases back to zero! Yaw/Heading and Pitch/Altitude varies +/- 180 degrees as expected. The 3d representation of the controller in the config utility is accurately portrayed in the window. However, with my current FreePIE script, I can observe some weirdness when the roll gets around +/-90 degrees.

I have deduced from Googling and barely understanding Wikipedia articles that what PSMoveServiceEX is outputting are "Tait-Bryan Angles", a convention commonly used by aircraft. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler_angles#Tait%E2%80%93Bryan_angles

I also believe what SteamVR is expecting are "Euler angles" https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler_angles

So the solution is obvious: We convert Tait-Bryan angles to Euler angles.

Huh?

So some more Googling and bad Wikipedia reading tells me there are two possible ways:

Tait-Bryan -> Quaternion -> Euler

Tait-Bryan -> Rotation Matrix -> Euler

(Tait-Bryan -> some magic formula -> Euler) HAH! I wish...

Hoo boy. Some serious maths here. Maths that make my head hurt.

Couldn't find an easily translatable example of Tait-Bryan Angles to Quaternation. All I was able to find was Tait-Bryan to Rotation Matrix, then Rotation Matrix to Euler Angles on Wikipedia. At least we aren't doing Matrix multiplication...yet...

Edit 2: Ok, so we copied Tait-Bryan Angles to Rotation matrix from Wikipedia (ZXY) https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler_angles#Tait%E2%80%93Bryan_angles
and Rotation Matrix to Euler-Angles ZXZ:

```
def tait_to_rmatrix(head,alt,bank):
    c1 = math.cos(head)
    c2 = math.cos(alt)
    c3 = math.cos(bank)
    s1 = math.sin(head)
    s2 = math.sin(alt)
    s3 = math.sin(bank)
    R = [(c1*c3)-(s1*s2*s3) , -(c2*s1) , (c1*s3)+(c3*s1*s2) , (c3*s1)+(c1*s2*s3) , c1*c2 , (s1*s3)-(c1*c3*s2) , -(c2*s3) , s2 , c2*c3]
    return R

def rmatrix_to_euler(R):
    yaw = math.atan(R[2]/-R[5])
    pitch = math.atan(math.sqrt(1-(R[8]*R[8]))/R[8])
    roll = math.atan(R[6]/R[7])
    return [yaw,pitch,roll]
 RmatrixR = tait_to_rmatrix(-freePieIO[idR].yaw,(freePieIO[idR].pitch+45),freePieIO[idR].roll) 
 eulerRout = rmatrix_to_euler(RmatrixR)
 diagnostics.watch(math.degrees(eulerRout[0]))
 diagnostics.watch(math.degrees(eulerRout[1]))
 diagnostics.watch(math.degrees(eulerRout[2]))
 hydra[indexR].x = (freePieIO[idR].x * 10)
 hydra[indexR].y = (freePieIO[idR].y * 10)
 hydra[indexR].z = (freePieIO[idR].z * 10)
 hydra[indexR].yaw = eulerRout[0]
 hydra[indexR].pitch = eulerRout[1]
 hydra[indexR].roll = eulerRout[2]
```

And of course I don't get it on the first try. The rotations in SteamVR make no sense. I'm going to sleep on it and give it another shot tomorrow.

Comment: Upon doing some Googling and reading of Wikipedia, I think the output of PSMoveServiceEX are Tait-Bryan Angles (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler_angles#Tait%E2%80%93Bryan_angles). Perhaps my solution is to figure out in what conditions I can calculate roll from 0 degrees, and in what conditions I can calculate it from 180 degrees...